# Mass rename of files in linux

Tags: linux, terminal

I have files i linux that are in format :

```
img_1234563_@_12345.XX-FFF-123334-35370-122232-12342.gif
img_1234fdfd3_fd12345.XX-FdFF-1233343-35370-145232-d12342.gif
```

that I would like to rename to the something like

```
img_1234fdfd3_fd12345.jpg
```

So cut all after first dot and put jpg at the end

I have tried to use for and  rename with pattern like img_/\S[//^.]+ 
but without much success :(

Comment: What is the actual command you used, and what was the result?

Comment: for i in *gif
do 
  mv -v "$i" "$(echo "$i" | sed -e 'img_/\S[//^.]+' - )"
done

Well am trying now something like this but still does not run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the String split to divide your file names. When having a variable `s` you can retain the shortest match of a pattern from the beginning using `${MYVAR/%pattern}`.

I do not know if you are processing all the entries on a directory so I suppose you have a variable `files` containing all the file names you need to rename. Otherwise you just need to change the loop bound to fit your list of files.

```
#!/bin/bash

files="img_1234563_@_12345.XX-FFF-123334-35370-122232-12342.gif img_1234fdfd3_fd12345.XX-FdFF-1233343-35370-145232-d12342.gif"

for file in $files; do
        name="${file/%.*}"
        fullName="${name}.jpg"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        mv "$file" "$fullName"
done
```